# XSLT: create new topic with results of search in table

Tags: xslt, dita

From a list of referenced glossentry topics I would like to get one table with the following result:

- column 1: the value of the glossterm element
- column 2: the value of glossdef element.

I start from one DITAMAP with references to "glossentry" topics.
In this glossentry topic I can find the two elements I want to use "glossterm" and "glossdef".

DITAMAP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
<title>Glossary</title>
<topicref href="gloss_ar3.dita" keys="ar3"/>
<topicref href="gloss_chr.dita" keys="chr"/>
</map>
```

glossentry 1 (gloss_ar3.dita):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" "glossary.dtd">
<glossentry id="glossentry_vhg_gt4_m2b">
<glossterm><sort-as value="AR3"/>AR3</glossterm>
<glossdef>Amplification Reagent 3</glossdef>
</glossentry>
```

Glossentry 2 (gloss_chr.dita):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" "glossary.dtd">
<glossentry id="glossentry_v1f_ktv_j2b">
<glossterm><sort-as value="Chr"/>Chr</glossterm>
<glossdef>Chromosome</glossdef>
</glossentry>
```

What I get with my code is a row per "glossentry" with:

- glossterm in the first column
- glossdef in the second column.

Result so far:

```
<row>
   <entry>AR3</entry>
   <entry>Amplification Reagent 3</entry>
</row>
<row>
   <entry>Chr</entry>
   <entry>Chromosome</entry>
</row>
```

So far so good.

But I would like to:

- have the rows in a regular table
- save it in a new file

This is my XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/map">
<xsl:apply-templates select="topicref"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="rows" match="topicref">
   <xsl:for-each select="document(@href)/glossentry">
      <row>     
      <entry><xsl:apply-templates select="glossterm"/></entry>
      <entry><xsl:apply-templates select="glossdef"/></entry>
      </row>
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The end-result should be:

- a table with the all terms & definition in a separate rows.
- saved in a separate file in the same folder as ditamap.

Example of the expected end-result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_ph2_kqz_fhb">
    <title>Glossary</title>
    <body>
        <p>
<table id="table_rzs_kqz_fhb">
<title/>
<tgroup cols="2">
<colspec colname="c1" colnum="1"/>
<colspec colname="c2" colnum="2"/>
<thead>
<row>
<entry>Term</entry>
<entry>Description</entry>
</row>
</thead>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry>AR3</entry>
<entry>Amplification Reagent 3</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Chr</entry>
<entry>Chromosome</entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
</p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

I am still new to XSLT. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What you show as the 'glossentry' document has only one entry and I see nothing linking it to the 'map' document.

Comment: I updated the code. Hope this is more clear.  Every glossentry topic has only one entry of glossterm and glossdef element.

Comment: I am still confused. Is the 'Example glossentry 1' document in a file named "gloss_ar3.dita"?

Comment: You're correct. I tried to make it more clear again in the description.

Comment: In DITA content processing the raw XML file should not be used as XSLT input. Rather pass DITA map file to [DITA-OT](https://www.dita-ot.org/) and using plug-in stylesheet to generate PDF or HTML is the most general way. So I think accepted XSLT 1.0 stylesheet is not the appropriate in actual DITA content publishing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/map">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="topicref">
            <xsl:variable name="gloss" select="document(@href)/glossentry" />
             <row>     
                <entry>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$gloss/glossterm"/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$gloss/glossdef"/>
                </entry>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming that for every `topicref` in the `map` document there is a file in the same directory whose name is equal to the value of the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you learn more deeply about DITA technology, especially specialization and key defintion/reference, you will know that there is no special XSLT stylesheet is needed to generate new topics for table styling.

Your requirement can be solved only changing DITA map & topic authoring.

- Use `glossaryTable` that is specialized from `simpletable`.
- Define keys for each `glossentry`

Here are authoring example:

Main DITA map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
    <title>Glossary Table Test</title>
    <mapref href="mKeydefMap.ditamap"/>
    <topicref href="GlossaryTableTest.dita"/>
</map>
```

Key definition DITA map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
    <title>Keydef Map</title>
    <keydef keys="AR3" href="gloss_ar3.dita"/>
    <keydef keys="CHR" href="gloss_chr.dita"/>
</map>
```

Glossenries: gloss_chr.dita and gloss_ar3.dita

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" "glossary.dtd">
<glossentry id="glossentry_v1f_ktv_j2b">
    <glossterm id="term"><sort-as value="Chr"/>Chr</glossterm>
    <glossdef id="def">Chromosome</glossdef>
</glossentry>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glossentry PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Glossary//EN" "glossary.dtd">
<glossentry id="glossentry_vhg_gt4_m2b">
    <glossterm id="term"><sort-as value="AR3"/>AR3</glossterm>
    <glossdef id="def">Amplification Reagent 3</glossdef>
</glossentry>
```

GlossaryTableTest.dita

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//ANTENNA HOUSE//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id="GlossaryTableTest">
    <title>Glossary Table Test</title>
    <conbody>
        <p>Glossary Table</p>
        <glossaryTable>
            <gtHead>
                <gtEntryHd>Term</gtEntryHd>
                <gtEntryHd>Definition</gtEntryHd>
            </gtHead>
            <gtRow>
                <gtEntry><glossterm conkeyref="AR3/term"/></gtEntry>
                <gtEntry><glossdef conkeyref="AR3/def"/></gtEntry>
            </gtRow>
            <gtRow>
                <gtEntry><glossterm conkeyref="CHR/term"></glossterm></gtEntry>
                <gtEntry><glossdef conkeyref="CHR/def"></glossdef></gtEntry>
            </gtRow>
        </glossaryTable>
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

The formatting result using [DITA-OT 3.3](https://www.dita-ot.org/) with [PDF5-ML](https://github.com/AntennaHouse/pdf5-ml)
[image: Formatting Result Using AH Formatter]

This solution uses `glossaryTable` specialization. You can see original specialization code [in GitHub](https://github.com/AntennaHouse/ah-dita/blob/master/com.antennahouse.dita.dita13.doctypes/doctypes/dtd/base/dtd/glossaryTableDomain.mod) As `glossaryTable` is specialized from `simpletable` there are *NO*  needs for stylesheet customization.